# Is there a limit on the number of entities you can query from the GAE datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

My GCM Endpoint is derived from the code at /github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints/root/src/main.  Each Android client device 
registers with the endpoint.  A message can be sent to the first 10 registered devices using this code:

```
@Api(name = "messaging", version = "v1", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "${endpointOwnerDomain}", ownerName = "${endpointOwnerDomain}", packagePath="${endpointPackagePath}"))
public class MessagingEndpoint {
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MessagingEndpoint.class.getName());

/** Api Keys can be obtained from the google cloud console */
private static final String API_KEY = System.getProperty("gcm.api.key");

/**
 * Send to the first 10 devices (You can modify this to send to any number of devices or a specific device)
 *
 * @param message The message to send
 */
public void sendMessage(@Named("message") String message) throws IOException {
    if(message == null || message.trim().length() == 0) {
        log.warning("Not sending message because it is empty");
        return;
    }
    // crop longer messages
    if (message.length() > 1000) {
        message = message.substring(0, 1000) + "[...]";
    }
    Sender sender = new Sender(API_KEY);
    Message msg = new Message.Builder().addData("message", message).build();
    List<RegistrationRecord> records = ofy().load().type(RegistrationRecord.class).limit(10).list();
    for(RegistrationRecord record : records) {
        Result result = sender.send(msg, record.getRegId(), 5);
        if (result.getMessageId() != null) {
            log.info("Message sent to " + record.getRegId());
            String canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
            if (canonicalRegId != null) {
                // if the regId changed, we have to update the datastore
                log.info("Registration Id changed for " + record.getRegId() + " updating to " + canonicalRegId);
                record.setRegId(canonicalRegId);
                ofy().save().entity(record).now();
            }
        } else {
            String error = result.getErrorCodeName();
            if (error.equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED)) {
                log.warning("Registration Id " + record.getRegId() + " no longer registered with GCM, removing from datastore");
                // if the device is no longer registered with Gcm, remove it from the datastore
                ofy().delete().entity(record).now();
            }
            else {
                log.warning("Error when sending message : " + error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The above code sends to the first 10 registered devices.  I would like to send to all registered clients.  According to http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/branches/allow-parent-filtering/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/cmd/Query.html#limit(int) setting limit(0) accomplishes this.  But I'm not convinced there will not be a problem for very large numbers of registered clients due to memory constraints or the time it takes to execute the query.  https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/Queries.wiki?repo=wiki states "Cursors let you take a "checkpoint" in a query result set, store the checkpoint elsewhere, and then resume from where you left off later.  This is often used in combination with the Task Queue API to iterate through large datasets that cannot be processed in the 60s limit of a single request".

Note the comment about the 60s limit of a single request.

So my question - if I modified the sample code at /github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints/root/src/main to request all objects from the datastore, by replacing limit(10) with limit(0), will this ever fail for a large number of objects?  And if it will fail, roughly what number of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a poor pattern, even with cursors. At the very least, you'll hit the hard 60s limit for a single request. And since you're doing updates on the `RegistrationRecord`, you need a transaction, which will slow down the process even more.

This is exactly what the task queue is for. The best way is to do it in two tasks:

1. Your api endpoint enqueues "send message to everyone" and returns immediately.
2. That first task is the "mapper" which iterates the `RegistrationRecord`s with a keys-only query. For each key, enqueue a "reducer" task for "send X message to this record".
3. The reducer task sends the message and (in a transaction) performs your record update.

Using Deferred this actually isn't much code at all.

The first task frees you client immediately and gives you 10m to iterating `RegistrationRecord` keys rather than the 60s limit for a normal request. If you have your chunking right and batch queue submissions, you should be able to generate thousands of reducer tasks per second.

This will effortlessly scale to hundreds of thousands of users, and might get you into millions. If you need to scale higher, you can apply a map/reduce approach to parallelize the mapping. Then it's just a question of how many instances you want to throw at the problem.

I have used this approach to great effect in the past sending out millions of apple push notifications at a time. The task queue is your friend, use it heavily.

Comment: Thanks stickfigure. Let's assume we have a queue of "reducer" tasks called reduceQueue.  You mentioned the "mapper task" should do chunking and batch queue submissions. Would it use a loop that calls reducerQueue.fetchStatistics.getNumTasks() in order to throttle the rate it enqueues the "reducer" tasks?  Or is there a better way for the "mapper" task to get feedback for use in its chunking and batching algorithm?  A link to a code example would be wonderful if you have one!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any public code samples for this, but it's really quite simple - you don't need to do anything speical WRT feedback. The mapper is literally "iterate the keys, for each key enqueue a reducertask". Start with that simple algorithm. To make it blistering fast, query with chunkSize 1000 and enqueue 1000 tasks per API call.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will time out if you try to retrieve too many entities. You will need to use cursors in your loop.

No one can say how many entities can be retrieved before this timeout - it depends on the size of your entities, complexity of your query, and, most importantly, what else happens in your loop. For example, in your case you can dramatically speed up your loop (and thus retrieve many more entities before a timeout) by creating tasks instead of building and sending messages within the loop itself.

Note that by default a query returns entities in chunks of 20 - you will need to increase the chunk size if you have a large number of entities.